# How do I initialize a lazy UISegmentedControl with items drawn from the Controller?

Tags: ios, swift, model-view-controller

I am a beginner in this whole MVC thing, so please bear with me.

I am trying to initialize a UISegmentedControl in the following way:

```
final class MyView: UIView {
    lazy var selector: UISegmentedControl = {
        let segmentedControl = UISegmentedControl(items: ["A", "B"])

        return segmentedControl
    }

    [...]

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: .zero)
        //autolayout, addsubview, etc..
    }
}
```

This works just fine. But I want to set up real data now as the segmented control's items, and I think those should come from the Controller. I tried using a delegate pattern like this:

```
protocol SegmentedControlDataSourceDelegate: class {
    func getData() -> [String]
}

final class MyView: UIView {
    weak var segmentedControlDataSource: SegmentedControlDataSourceDelegate!
    lazy var selector: UISegmentedControl = {
        let segmentedControl = UISegmentedControl(items: self.segmentedControlDataSource.getData())

        return segmentedControl
    }

    [...]

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: .zero)
        //autolayout, addsubview, etc..
    }
}
```

This won't work, as the delegate is added after the initialization of the view, like this in the ViewController:

```
let myView = MyView()
self.view = myView
myView.segmentedControlDataSource = self
```

*(and the ViewController implements the delegate's `getData()` method)*

Since the segmented control is a lazy variable, it won't be computed again and it is initialized with no delegate before the delegate is actually set, throwing an error.

How should I modify my code to be able to query the items from the ViewController, preserving MVC separation? Or where do I go wrong with my assumptions about MVC?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There can be 2 approaches one can use. I am mentioning both of them use the one that best fits your usecase.

1) Write a convenience initializer for your custom view class with segments item as the parameter i.e.

```
class MyView: UIView {

    var items: [String]

    lazy var selector: UISegmentedControl = {
        let segmentedControl = UISegmentedControl(items: self.items)
        return segmentedControl
    }()

    init(items: [String]) {
        self.items = items
        super.init(frame: .zero)
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

> The above approach will only work if you have the items when initializing the view and you don't need to fetch them for some server or backend.

2) You can add dummy segments at the time of UISegmentedControl initialization and update them with the real values or initialize the UISegmentedControl without any segment and insert them later on i.e.

```
lazy var selector: UISegmentedControl = {
   let segmentedControl = UISegmentedControl()
   segmentedControl.frame = CGRect(x: 100, y: 100, width: 80, height: 50)
   return segmentedControl
}()
```

Initialize the segmentedControl as above and add the below method to update from the datasource.

```
func updateSegmentControlWithItems(_ items: [String]) {
    //If no segments were added
    items.enumerated().forEach { (offset, element) in
        self.selector.insertSegment(withTitle: element, at: offset, animated: true)
    }

    //If dummy segments were added
    items.enumerated().forEach { (offset, element) in
        self.selector.setTitle(element, forSegmentAt: offset)
    }
}
```

> The above approach works best when you need to fetch segments titles
>   as a result from any async task. I think there is no need for the
>   delegate because the class that is creating that view(MyView) has its
>   reference so why not store that reference and call the
>   updateSegmentControlWithItems() when there are items. Delegates are
>   effective when you need to send data in backward direction i.e. form
>   MyView to the class that is creating that view.

Comment: you might just be right. i have other delegates in this class, and they work the other way, and no such issue came up with those. I have probably overengineered this, when I truly have a reference already to the view in the viewcontroller. i could just use that to set the items. thank you for your answer and the detailed explanation.

Answer (score 1):

You could implement an `updateSegmentedControl()` method in view like this:

```
func updateSegmentedControl() {
    self.selector.removeAllSegments()
    for segment in self.segmentedControlDataSource?.getData() {
        self.selector.insertSegment(withTitle: segment, at: self.selector.numberOfSegments, animated: false)

    }
}
```

And call that whenever the data changes (and after setting the delegate)

Also, you're setting the view's delegate with `myView.delegate = self`, where you need `myView.segmentedControlDataSource = self`

Your segmentedControlDataSource is implicitly unwrapped, which may cause crashes. You should declare it like this:

```
weak var segmentedControlDataSource: SegmentedControlDataSourceDelegate?
```

One other thing - selector name works, but it represents something else in swift: [link](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/using_objective-c_runtime_features_in_swift), which may be confusing

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Indeed I messed up the delegate name, but your solution will give a needless cycle - I would have to call this method from the viewcontroller so there is no need for the delegate. Which might just be true based on Najeeb’s answer. but this might be because i wasnkt clear enough.

Comment: In this case, yes, you could just pass the data to the function without the delegate. 

There's no way to do it just with delegate (maybe "datasource" would be a better name?) - your view needs to know when the data changes.
This is how `UITableView` works with `reloadData()`.